# Error while instantiating an InceptionResNetV2 in eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
tensorFlow version (use command below): 1.10
Python version:3.6
OS Platform: window 10
```

Describe the problem:

i used the `tf.enable_eager_execution()` and create InceptionResNetV2 mode from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/InceptionResNetV2) will be error and only InceptionResNetV2 have. I need use `tf.enable_eager_execution()` can't without.

how to fix it?

create mode

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
image_model =tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

error

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
----> 1 image_model =tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\inception_resnet_v2.py in InceptionResNetV2(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes)
304 for block_idx in range(1, 11):
305 x = inception_resnet_block(
--> 306 x, scale=0.17, block_type='block35', block_idx=block_idx)
307
308 # Mixed 6a (Reduction-A block): 17 x 17 x 1088

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\inception_resnet_v2.py in inception_resnet_block(x, scale, block_type, block_idx, activation)
187 output_shape=K.int_shape(x)[1:],
188 arguments={'scale': scale},
--> 189 name=block_name)([x, up])
190 if activation is not None:
191 x = Activation(activation, name=block_name + '_ac')(x)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
745 input_shapes = nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.shape, inputs)
746
--> 747 output_shapes = self.compute_output_shape(input_shapes)
748 output_shapes = nest.flatten(output_shapes)
749 outputs = [

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
678
679 def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
--> 680 input_shape = tuple(tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list())
681
682 if self._output_shape is None:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in init(self, dims)
539 else:
540 # Got a list of dimensions
--> 541 self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
542 self._ndims = None
543

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in (.0)
539 else:
540 # Got a list of dimensions
--> 541 self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
542 self._ndims = None
543

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in as_dimension(value)
480 return value
481 else:
--> 482 return Dimension(value)
483
484

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in init(self, value)
35 raise TypeError("Cannot convert %s to Dimension" % value)
36 else:
---> 37 self._value = int(value)
38 if (not isinstance(value, compat.bytes_or_text_types) and
39 self._value != value):

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TensorShape'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. There are a couple of problems with your question, both of which are likely to prevent busy community members from choosing this question for their attention (you will see that someone has already downvoted it). Firstly, please add some carriage returns to your error text so that it doesn't scroll horizontally - it's almost impossible to read as it stands. Secondly, please clarify your problem statement, it is quite difficult to understand at present. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a bug running `tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2()` when `tf.enable_eager_execution()` is enabled. I see that a community member has already filed a bug issue on the [TensorFlow Github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21872).